# Windows Live ID login via HttpRequest

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httprequest, windows-live-id

I want interact with one web via HttpRequest/HttpResponse. But the web requires login via Windows Live ID. I go to the live login page, but I can't get any usable response from login page.

The code used to access the login page:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://login.live.com/");
request.Timeout = 30000; 
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"; 
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"; 
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5"); 
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"); 
request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "300"); 
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); 
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get; 

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And the response:

> Cookies must be allowed
>
> Your browser is currently set to block cookies.
>   Your browser must allow cookies before
>   you can use Windows Live ID.
>
> Cookies are small text files stored on
>   your computer that tell Windows Live
>   ID sites and services when you're
>   signed in. To learn how to allow
>   cookies, see online help in your web
>   browser.

I have no problem with cookies on another web pages and I can't found any way, how to get over this message.

Do you anybody have an idea, how to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the capacity property for CookieContainer object.

```
....
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a complete tutorial on how to access Windows Live ID with C# and building the client.

Read here: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Hotmail-Exposed-Access-Hotmail-using-C-sharp/