# How to get Windows 8 Live ID

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, liveid

Windows 8 uses Live ID as the user name. How do I get this LiveID in C#?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? More data would help...

Answer (score 6):

Metro apps by design have restricted access to many information they shouldn't really need, and I think this might be one of them.

WinRT gives access to `Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation` class (as CodeCaster suggested), but as I checked, from all the methods there only `GetDisplayNameAsync()` might return live id (email) and it's only if the first/last name are not set on the account.

(Also, most of the methods in this class require setting *Enterprise Authentication* capability, which is [not really welcome in the Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx). And [the documentation of the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation) is currently poor.)

For [single-sign-on experience](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465097.aspx), you might rather use Live Software Development Kit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following post:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Live-SDK-in-Windows-8-XAML-C-Metro-Applications.aspx

also on previous questions:

[Log in to desktop application by Windows Live ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539593/log-in-to-desktop-application-by-windows-live-id)

[Windows Live ID login via HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814594/windows-live-id-login-via-httprequest)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation) contain some relevant data.

Comment: I tried reference the Windows.System namespace, but I can't find it in a newly created WPF solution, even if the solution is using .NET Framework 4.5, can you tell me how do I see the namespace of Windows.System? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1343145 - it is a WinRT only feature, not a .NET 4.5 feature